# critical points of projection function on low dimensional set

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, differential-geometry, lagrange-multiplier, morse-theory

Suppose $S = \{x \in \mathbb{R}^n | P(x) = 0\}$, for some polynomial $P$, and I want to find the critical points of $f: S \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ which takes $(x_1, \ldots, x_n) \mapsto x_1$. It is clear to me that the critical points are contained in the set of solutions of $\{P(x) = 0, \frac{\partial P}{x_2} = \ldots = \frac{\partial P}{x_n} = 0\}$.

I now have a situation where I have a function $g: \mathbb{R^k} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, and I embed the graph of $g$ into $\mathbb{R}^n$ taking $(x_1,\ldots, x_{k+1}) \rightarrow (x_1,\ldots, x_{k+1}, 0, \ldots, 0)$. Let us call the graph $G \subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$. Now consider $G \cap S$. I want to obtain the critical points of $f: G \cap S \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, again taking $(x_1, \ldots, x_n) \mapsto x_1$. I am finding that the critical points in this case are contained in the set of solutions of $\{G, P(x) = 0, \frac{\partial P}{x_2} = \ldots = \frac{\partial P}{x_{k}} = 0\}$. I want to understand why this works. Specifically, why are only $k-1$ partial derivatives enough?

Here are my thoughts. First, $G$ has dimension $k$, so $G \cap S$ has dimension $k-1$, so as a sanity check it makes sense that I would only need $k-1$ partial derivatives. However, what does setting only $k-1$ partial derivatives of $P$ to $0$ even mean geometrically? Any insight would be great.

(assume there is no degeneracy anywhere, and everything is smooth and nice)

Comment: I am very very sorry, but that question had some awful typos. I think I have corrected them now.

Comment: First, $G\cap S$ could have any dimension from $0$ to $k$ when not empty. The most general situation would be $k-1$ dimensions, but it could be that $G\subset S$, so there is no decrease of dimension, or that they only intersect tangentially. For example in $\Bbb R^3$ with $P(x) = x_1^2 + x_2^2 + x_3^2 - 1$ and $g(x_1,x_2) = \sqrt{1-x_1^2 + x_2^2}$ for the first case, and $g(x_1,x_2) = 1$ for the second.

Comment: To find the critical values of the restriction of $f$ to $G\cap S$ means differentiating in directions *inside* $G\cap S$, the partial derivatives with respect to $x_1$ through $x_{k+1}$ have components inside $G\cap S$, so they are relevant. The partial derivatives with respect to $x_{k+2}, \dots, x_n$ all have no component inside $G\cap S$, so they tell nothing useful to finding the critical values of this restriction of $f$. Note though that I included $x_{k+1}$ in the first group, while you excluded it. You'll have to justify that exclusion.

Comment: In my situation, I have a guarantee that $G \cap S$ will have dimension $k-1$ (the intersection is transversal). I excluded $x_{k+1}$ because that way I would have an overdetermined system. After $G$ and $P(x) = 0$, I must only have $k-1$ more equations.